# Is "accept" correct in this case?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

This is an example sentence from my student's book:

> Furthermore, pupils in cities are able to **accept** better education.

[Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/accept?q=accept) says *accept* means:

> to take willingly something that is offered; to say ‘yes’ to an offer, invitation, etc.

I know the original meaning of the example sentence is "cities usually have better educational resources" but should *accept* be used here?

If *accept* is correct, would  students in the countryside *reject* better education?

Comment: I'm sure it's a typo. Should be *pupils in cities are able to **access** better education*

Comment: Who wrote your 'student's book'? Are they native English speakers? Is it from a big and reputable publisher?

Comment: Google can't find the string "**Furthermore, pupils in cities are able to**" anywhere on the Internet or in Google Books. And their indexes ignore case and punctuation, so this looks like a complete one-off. But it's pretty obviously a typo / erroneous "autocorrect".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a typo

Comment: ...there are several instances of ["able to access better education"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22able+to+access+better+education%22) in Google Books, but [No results found for "able to accept better education".](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22able+to+accept+better+education%22)

Comment: In fact, It is named 学能评价, a teaching aid recommended by the Ministry of Education of Zhejiang Province, China.

Comment: I see. It's about **Chinglish**. The expression is suitable in Chinese, but not in English 

Comment: A decent sentence with a specialized context could be found to make **accept** work, but it takes work: "Pupils in cities are able to accept better education with higher demands when their new teachers come from their own population, and not Washington D.C."

Comment: @YosefBaskin   When have teachers ever come from Washington D.C? In the sense of being dispatched by the federal government?

Comment: I was using an odd example of non-local contributors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Summarize the current conclusion)

It's Chinglish or a typo.

Recommended expression:

- *access* better education
- *get* better education